# Salt Lake City Temple : side tower windows

Tags: building

I've been challenged to build the [Salt Lake City LDS Temple](https://deseret.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/107638a/2147483647/strip/true/crop/3000x1688+0+0/resize/2000x1125!/quality/90/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.vox-cdn.com%2Fthumbor%2FJgVN1lxbViWnBQUO_ctglfdLaXE%3D%2F0x0%3A3000x1688%2F3000x1688%2Ffilters%3Afocal%281500x844%3A1501x845%29%2Fcdn.vox-cdn.com%2Fuploads%2Fchorus_asset%2Ffile%2F23819583%2Fnorthbirdseye.jpeg).  I've made some progress on the main wall, but the side towers are a bit difficult.  Can I get some tips on how to make the dark slit in the middle and the decorative piece above each window?

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to build:

[image: Partial photograph of the LDS temple]

Here's what I've done so far (just imagine it all in gray)
[image: main]
[image: side]

Comment: At what scale are you building this - minifig scale, microscale, other? What's the (approximate) height (in bricks) of a storey, or of a window slit?

Comment: Please post pictures of your attempt that could be used to improve your approach.

Comment: It's about minifig scale.  The main side will probably be about 48 studs wide, and then 10 or 12 studs for each set of side towers/steeples. I'll post pictures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I'm gonna suggest you pop the columns out and use octogonal 2x2 bricks for the tower columns. Enhancing these details is an easy way to convey the architecture of the building:

[image: top view of assembly]

For the slit, I'll propose a SNOT assembly with vertical plates. There are several ways to achieve this, but since I can see some [1x1 plates with thick ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4081b), here's a possible assembly (including a [jumper plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3794a)):

[image: SNOT assembly]

The assembly rests one brick below the window baseline, and the jumper plate makes it possible to align it properly. You'll need some internal scaffolding, though.

[image: Front view of whole assembly]

Here's a view from the back to illustrate this alignment:

[image: Back view of SNOT assembly alignment]

If you prefer the slit to be dark instead of see-thru, you can use a 1x3 black plate.

And, of course, remember that this is not the only way of building a SNOT assembly for the slit - I'm sure you can make alternative arrangements that should be easy to hide inside the tower.

Comment: Ivan's solution worked well - thanks. The only change I'd mention is that since I'm using 1x3 arches I'm not using the jumper plate to center the dark backdrop.

Comment: Judging by the photograph of the temple, it seems that the width of the windows in the towers is roughly equal to the windows on the main wall - that's why I opted for a two-stud-wide arch. Also, note it's good stackexchange etiquette to [accept an answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm glad you've found an acceptable solution already. As IvanSanchez points our there are multiple ways to build such a solution.

To me the slits seem to resemble the narrow windows for firing arrows in the current (as of November 2022) [Lion King's castle](https://www.lego.com/en-de/product/lion-knights-castle-10305) set, so I looked at how those were constructed.

Reading the instruction (which can be found [here](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6429213.pdf) on the LEGO website), the first time one of these slit windows is built is in steps 77-79, and consists of two tiles (e.g. FLAT TILE 1x3, Design ID: 63864), oriented vertically on either side of the window; each supported by "BRICK 1X1X1 2/3, W/ VERT. KNOBS" (Design ID: 32952).