# Salt Lake Temple: Downward facing triangles

Tags: building, design

Another question in my SLC temple series:
How can I replicate the downward facing triangles in the stonework of some of the spire/columns.  Currently I'm planning on just using cheese slopes but those are kind of square.  I could maybe use [quarter tiles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25269&name=Tile,%20Round%201%20x%201%20Quarter&category=%5BTile,%20Round%5D#T=C&C=86) but they're not quite the same either.
[image: stonework]
[image: stonework with triangles highlighted]

Comment: How wide is that section gonna be, 8 studs maybe? Off the top of my heads, plain studs-out might just work.

Comment: Or SNOT [15208 1x2 plate with 3 teeth](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15208#T=C&C=85).

Comment: Please post some pictures of your attempt to replicate this. It would give a sense of scale and accuracy we are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure if you could engineer this into a question, but I'd love to see the end result of your temple when you've finished!

Comment: @NeilTarrant that is why we have comments and chat!  :-)

Comment: This really depends on the scale you're going for. At least roughly how wide is that section/tower going to be in the final model? A few studs? An entire 32-footprint? Anything in between? It largely depends on how detailed the whole rest of the building is.

Comment: To answer Neil Tarrant's question, I post updates for this build on the lego creations group at https://www.facebook.com/groups/519139904928934

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by a [previous question by @MonteGardner](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17520/salt-lake-city-temple-side-tower-windows), I'll assume that the build is mainly in light bluish gray ("bley") colour, and the distance between the columns of a tower (the length of the downward triangle strips) is 8 studs.

I'll suggest using [1x1 plate with tooth](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=49668&colorID=86) for the triangles (with some SNOT supports and tiles for the battlements), plus [slope 75° 2x2x3](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3685&colorID=86) for the pyramid endings.

[image: CAD drawing of battlements assembly]

[image: CAD drawing of battlements assembly, exploded]

Comment: In a comment on the question, you suggested "1x2 plate with 3 teeth", as that would give 12 "teeth" on 8 studs, and there are 13-14 "triangles" on the picture that would come closer.

Comment: Unfortunately "1x2 plate with 3 teeth" is not available in light grey colour.

Comment: Ahh, that's a good reason not to choose it.