# Salt Lake City Temple: Temple doors

Tags: building, design

I'm building the lds temple in Salt Lake City in lego. I'd like to represent the temple doors as [seen here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/gs-waymarking-images/c093836b-88ba-42f9-af38-1e8ec75bfda7.jpg):

[image: actual door]

My current plan is to use the [stockade](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87601&name=Door%201%20x%205%20x%208%201/2%20Stockade&category=%5BDoor%5D#T=C) as the base door:

[image: door part]

...and probably put a plate over it then use [2x2 pearl gold plates](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3022&C=115#T=C&C=115) for the background, then put some decorated 2x2 rounded tiles such as [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14769pb116&C=115#T=C&C=115) or [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14769pb572&C=115#T=C&C=115).  Can anyone suggest an approach to represent the gold filigrees in between or any other part of this?

Answer (score 6):

Judging by some photographs, the size of the doors is roughly the same as that of the window arches, and judging by [one of your previous questions](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17520/salt-lake-city-temple-side-tower-windows), those are 2 studs wide and about 4 bricks high.

Therefore, I suggest building the doors at that size: 2 studs wide. IMO the right size will help the build as a whole, even if you have to sacrifice detail. Something like the following should work:

[image: door assembly]

Parts:

- [1x2 brick with studs on side, reddish brown](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11211&idColor=88)
- [1x2 plate with rail, pearl gold](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32028&idColor=115)
- [1x1 round tile, nougat with red circle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138pb057)
- [1x1 round tile, trans-clear with octagonal jewel pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138pb024)
- 1x2 brick, trans-clear (should be partially hidden behind a 1x4 arch)